# How to make three buttons at bottom of screen more towards the center

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I make the three buttons at the bottom be "tighter" and more close to the center? I tried to play around with padding, but it only went "inward" a tiny bit

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Memorize!")
                .font(.title)
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 75))]) {
                    ForEach(emojis, id: \.self, content: { emoji in
                        CardView(content: emoji).aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    })
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            Spacer()
            HStack() {
                VStack {
                    vehicleButton
                    Text("Vehicles")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    animalButton
                    Text("Animals")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    faceButton
                    Text("Faces")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }
            }
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
```

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5UXJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Spacer()` views inside your `HStack` will push the buttons as far out from each other as possible.

If you want the items closer to the centre, you should remove them and instead use the `HStack` constructor's `spacing:` argument to govern the space between elements:

```swift
HStack(spacing: 20) { // adjust accordingly
  VStack {
    vehicleButton
    Text("Vehicles")
      .font(.footnote)
      .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
  }
  VStack {
    animalButton
    Text("Animals")
      .font(.footnote)
      .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
  }
  VStack {
    faceButton
    Text("Faces")
      .font(.footnote)
      .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
  }
}
```

The `HStack` overall will be centered, because that's the default alignment of its parent `VStack`. However, because the individual child items theoretically have different widths, individually they might not look quite centered (say, if one ends up with a caption that's wider than the icon). You could apply a `.frame(width:)` modifier to each VStack if you needed to.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it bad practice to encode a number into the spacing argument? Because 20 may look good for iPhone 12 but not iPhone 6, for example.

Comment: @erfgerwge in my experience, if you are going to use actual numbers for your spacing argument, make sure it looks really good on iPhone 12. Then go back and use simple math to calculate that number. Should come out looking great on iPhone6 and iPad even if done correctly.

Comment: Once you have a value that works, it's also not a bad idea to declare it as a `@ScaledMetric(relativeTo:)` variable so that it can adjust to the user's font accessibility settings.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want those spacer between the buttons, that is making them to not get together. Put spacers at the beginning and end and use padding for the spacing between buttons.

```
HStack() {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                vehicleButton
                Text("Vehicles")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
            VStack {
                animalButton
                Text("Animals")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }.padding(.horizontal, 20)
            VStack {
                faceButton
                Text("Faces")
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
```